# Multiply matrix by list in Python

Tags: python, multiplication

I am looking for a way to achieve the following in Python and can't figure out how to do it:

```
a=[[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
b=[1,0,5]

c=hocuspocus(a,b)

--> c=[[0,1],[0,0],[5,5]]
```

So basically I would like to multiply the different matrix rows in **a** with the list **b**.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: will `b` always be a list with the same length as `a`, and will `a` always consist of pairs?

Comment: let's say you work out an algorithm, how do you distinguish between b beeing row vector and column vector...

Comment: based on the answer he's expecting, he's not doing matrix multiplication. If 'a' is 3 rows x 2 columns, 'b' is 1 row x 3 columns (bad notation for 'b'); then a*b is not possible but b*a is - which would be `[[5, 6]]` using the correct notation (1 row x 2 columns).

Comment: Indeed, I didn't quite formulate my question correctly. I should be: how can I multiply matrix **rows** by a list.

Comment: It seems Linear programming: Ax = b

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
hocuspocus = lambda a,b: [[r*q for r in p] for p, q in zip(a,b)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Numpy](https://numpy.org/), it has a function for cross multiplying, and other useful tools for matricies.

```
import * from numpy as np

a=[[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
b=[1,0,5]

prod = a * b
```

Comment: Numpy is the right tool, but OP wants a matrix product rather than `np.cross` (which gives a 3x3 array here).

Answer (score 0):

Python lists don't support that behaviour directly, but [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) arrays do matrix multiplication (and various other matrix operations that you might want) directly:

```
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1]])
>>> b
array([1, 0, 5])
>>> a * b
array([[0, 0, 5],
       [1, 0, 5]])
```